# JavaWS APPLICATION_TEMPLATE.JNLP causes crash

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have a swing application that is launched via Java WebStart. Upon moving to Java 8 I have the following problem.

Using the following MYAPP.jnlp file with the attached APPLICATION_TEMPLATE.JNLP file included in the JNLP-INF directory of the MyApp.jar file.

/MYAPP.jnlp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="$$codebase" href="MYAPP.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Test App</title>
        <vendor>Test Vendor</vendor>
        <homepage href="docs/help.html"/>
        <description>A Test Application</description>
        <icon href="images/IMG.gif"/>
        <icon kind="splash" href="images/IMGSplash.jpg"/>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <java version="1.8+ 1.7+"/>
        <property name="swing.defaultlaf" value="com.test.test.MyLookAndFeel"/>
        <property name="sun.java2d.noddraw" value="true"/>
        <property name="jnlp.versionEnabled" value="true" />
        <jar href="MyApp.jar" version="4.3.5" main="true"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="com.test.test.MySwingFrame">
        <argument>configFile=$$site/TEST.config</argument>
        <argument>envFile=$$site/TEST.properties</argument>
        <argument>logConfigFile=$$site/logback.xml</argument>
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

JNLP-INF/APPLICATION_TEMPLATE.JNLP

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="*" href="MYAPP.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Test App</title>
        <vendor>Test Vendor</vendor>
        <homepage href="docs/help.html"/>
        <description>A Test Application</description>
        <icon href="images/IMG.gif"/>
        <icon kind="splash" href="images/IMGSplash.jpg"/>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <java version="1.8+ 1.7+"/>
        <property name="swing.defaultlaf" value="com.test.test.MyLookAndFeel"/>
        <property name="sun.java2d.noddraw" value="true"/>
        <property name="jnlp.versionEnabled" value="true" />
        <jar href="MyApp.jar" version="4.3.5" main="true"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="com.test.test.MySwingFrame">
        <argument>*</argument>
        <argument>*</argument>
        <argument>*</argument>
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

When putting the above APPLICATION_TEMPLATE.JNLP file into JNLP-INF Java Webstart fails silently after installing the application. I can't find any trace of an error in the trace logs and the console window does not even open up. When removing only the APPLICATION_TEMPLATE.JNLP the application launches.

Has anyone had any success signing a JNLP file via APPLICATION_TEMPLATE.JNLP?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My advice is to try the following things:

1. Change the java security level of your machine to medium (Control Panel -> Java -> Security tab)
2. Clear all java cache ( Control Panel -> Java -> View...)
3. open cmd, set the path of your java home (java 8), open the jnlp file using 'javaws' command..